# (OAuthException - #100) Invalid verification code format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I have using the Facebook login authentication on the C# ASP.NET MVC application.

Facebook assembly reference: Facebook.7.0.6

Used the below code for getting user details,

```
dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new { client_id = xxxx, client_secret = xxxx, redirect_uri = xxxx, code = code });
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)");
```

**For some times only**, I got a below exception if trying to get the user details,
(some times it's working properly)

> Exception Message : **(OAuthException - #100) Invalid verification code**

> format. at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper
> httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean
> containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags) at
> Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object
> parameters, Type resultType) at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String
> path, Object parameters)

I can't able to find the exact root cause of this issue.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance,